# Connected android device is not showing up in android studio in m1 Mac mini

Tags: google-pixel, macos, android-studio

I have installed android studio in m1 Mac mini and connected pixel-5 to it. The device is not listing, instead it is showing "loading devices". I have the same setup in intel MacBook Pro and it is showing the pixel-5 when connected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled on the phone Developer Options and then "Android Debug Bridge" option?

Comment: Is the ADB working? Try `adb` on the terminal (whether inside Android Studio or from Mac's)

Comment: @Robert the developer option is enabled already

Comment: @AndrewT. the adb seems to be working, checked adb devices and the device is showing

Comment: Fixed the issue, I tried with sample code from android studio itself, for that the a specific sdk version was missing. Installed that and after syncing Gradle file, the device is showing now.